# spring data mongodb full text search with And operator

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring data mongodb for full text search.

My User domain class is something like:

```html
@Document
public class User implements UserDetails{
 
 @TextIndexed
 private String name;
 @TextIndexed
    private String location;
}
```

And I have two user objects:

```html
user1(name:"dk",location:"Gurgaon, Haryana, India");
user2(name:"Peter",location:"india");
```

Now I want to search user **"dk"** for location **"india"**.

For that I create a TextCriteria like:
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matching("dk").matching("india");

And It search both two users i.e. user1 and user2. that was expected in the case of machingAny(String...texts).

How I can create a and query that match both the words to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spring-data-mongodb you can do this in that way

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingPhrase("dk").matchingPhrase("india")
```

For more information you can read from this
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases